# Setting multiple base params

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4

Is there any build-in method to set several base params. `setExtraParam: function(name, value)` method can set only one param.

Answer (score 0):

The `setExtraParam` method manipulates the `extraParam` config object. It sets the value of a field within that object.

As such, it can be repeatedly called with different names.

```
proxy.setExtraParam('param1', 'value1');
proxy.setExtraParam('param2', 'value2');
```

The values will be merged together into a single `extraParams` object. Alternatively, you can set the `extraParams` object directly:

```
proxy.extraParams = { 'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2' };
```

(Note that in ExtJs 5, you really should use the `setExtraParams` method instead)

Example code: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7t9

Comment: `ReferenceError: setExtraParams is not defined`

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, I misread the tag as ExtJS5, not ExtJS4. Answer updated.